# How to get data from two rows into one single cell? - SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of distinct patients broken out by insurance coverage but some people have multiple insurance coverages. So right now a patient with two coverages is on two rows. How do I get them into one row and show both coverages in a single cell broken out by a semi-colon?

This is my current output:

| PAT_ID | INS |
| --- | --- |
| 34792133 | Medicare |
| 34792133 | Self-Pay |

Hoping to return something like this:

| PAT_ID | INS |
| --- | --- |
| 34792133 | Medicare; Self-Pay |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select pat_id, listagg(ins, '; ') within group (order by ins) 
from t
group by pat_id;
```